# How do I put a dialog box to pop up on any row I click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code of a table and I want that anywhere I click on a certain for a dialog Box to pop up. For example, if I have

```
Jazz 3  4  jazzy
Ram 5 7 Ruth
John 6 88 Jujube
```

That if I click on 88 I get the details for john in a dialog box or if I click on Ruth I get details for Ram.

**Code**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $('#tableItems').on('click', 'tr', function() {
       var row = $(this).find('td:first').text();
       alert('You clicked ' + row);
    });
</script>

    <th style='width:75%;'>Janurary</th>
                        <th style='width:75%;'>February</th>
                        <th style='width:75%;'>March</th>
                        <th style='width:75%;'>April</th>
                        <th style='width:75%;'>May</th>
                        <th style='width:75%;'>June</th>
                        <th style='width:75%;'>July</th>
    while($row=pg_fetch_array($result))
{ ?>
<tr>
 <td style= "font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 3px solid"><?php echo $row['client_id'] ?></td>

    <td style="padding:0px !important; border-bottom: 3px solid">

         <span style="height:50%;width:100%;display: inline-block; background-color: #fcf8e3; font-weight: bold; padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px;font-size:14">
            <?php echo "Charges";?>
         </span>
               <span style="height:50%;width:100%;border-top:1px solid black; display: inline-block; background-color: #dff0d8; font-weight: bold;  padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;font-size:14">
             <?php echo "Payments";?>
                 </span>
</td>
<?php   for ($x=1;$x<=12;$x++){
          $val=strlen($x);
         if($val<2)
         {
         $query1= "Select sum(charge_amount) from charge where client_id= '".$row['client_id']."' AND to_char(charge_entry_date,'YYYY-MM') = '".$year."-". '0'.$x."'";
         $query2= "Select sum(paid_amount) from payment where client_id = '".$row['client_id']."' AND to_char(entry_date, 'YYYY-MM') ='". $year."-". '0'.$x."'";

            }
            else
            {
    $query1= "Select sum(charge_amount) from charge where client_id= '".$row['client_id']."' AND to_char(charge_entry_date,'YYYY-MM') = '".$year."-".$x."'";
    $query2= "Select sum(paid_amount) from payment where client_id = '".$row['client_id']."' AND to_char(entry_date, 'YYYY-MM') ='". $year."-".$x."'";
}



    $result1= pg_query($conn,$query1);
        $row2=pg_fetch_array($result1);


        $result2= pg_query($conn,$query2);


        $row3=pg_fetch_array($result2);

        /////
        $val2=strlen($x-1);
        if($val2<2)
        { 

    else{


    $q= "Select sum(charge_amount) from charge where client_id= '".$row['client_id']."' AND to_char(charge_entry_date,'YYYY-MM') = '".$year."-".($x-1)."'";
        $q2= "Select sum(paid_amount) from payment where client_id = '".$row['client_id']."' AND to_char(entry_date, 'YYYY-MM') ='". $year."-".($x-1) ."'";

        } 
        $r=pg_query($conn,$q);
        $row5=pg_fetch_array($r);

        $r2=pg_query($conn,$q2);
        $row6=pg_fetch_array($r2);


        ////

 ?> 

     <td style="padding:0px !important; border-bottom: 3px solid">
     <span style="height:50%;width:100%;display: inline-block;background-color: #fcf8e3; padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px;font-size:14; white-space: nowrap">
     <?php if ($row2['sum'] == NULL)
    {
    echo "0.00";
} `else{
`


     echo number_format($row2['sum'], 2, '.', ',');

     if($x==01){
                  echo "";        }

      else if($row2['sum']>$row5['sum'])

   {
```

... and other echos

Comment: What's the problem with this code? Untested, but it should basically work..

Comment: can you share html as well?

Comment: If this is not working, check the HTML. The code looks okay.

Comment: Use [jquery dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) to open a dialog box, but before that you have to fetch the data of the specific item that you have clicked

Comment: Please share your HTML with us. It's hard to tell what's wrong when we can't see all of the code that is being used to try and get this to work.

Comment: ok ill share the code now

Comment: i shared it please take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, i think this is what you want..

Here is the **snippet**

```js
$(function(){
$(document).on("click","table tr td",function(){
  $(".modal").modal("show");
var curr_tr = $(this).closest("tr");
  var td_length = $(curr_tr).find("td").length;
  $("#data").empty();
  for(var i =0; i< td_length; i++)
  {
    $("#data").append($(curr_tr).find("td:eq("+i+")").html()+"  ");
  }
});
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Mor</td>
    <td>Ruth</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <p id="data"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: can you make it into a dialog box? and without the --> arrow out puts?

Comment: sure! check the snippet again.

Answer (score 0):

Your `jQuery` seems to be working fine. I would go over your html and more closely to make sure all of your syntax is right.

I'm not very familiar with `PHP` so it's hard for me to tell what exactly is going on in your code.

But as you can see from this example, your `jQuery` code is working just fine:
https://jsfiddle.net/exxtvs0g/